# Sonarlint (3.1)/SonarQube(5.6.6) on Eclipse (neon) not checking Java files

Tags: java, eclipse, sonarqube, sonarlint, sonarlint-eclipse

I have a workspace that I want to analyze with my rules configured on the SonarQube server. The code in the workspace is not in any code repository (so far).

So I installed SonarLint(3.1) in Eclipse(neon3 but same issues in edit: neon2), but did not get any reports. In fact when at some point I saw a log, it said for a project with over 50+ Java files, it would check only 8 files.

The java projects are maven projects and the code is stored under src/main/java/com/....some package ... /SomeFile.java

The same result appears whether in unconnected mode, or in connected mode, connected to a server-side project with Java measures ("SonarQube way" selected).

So I can't right now use SonarLint at all with Eclipse!

Comment: Does your project, your files have "Test" in their name ? If yes they are excluded by Sonarlint default preferences

Comment: No, there is no "test" in the name, I checked the regexp in the preferences against the name.

Comment: What happens if you select your project, and in Eclipse's Quick Access choose Analyze - Analuze with SonarLint?

Comment: Thanks, that was a good hint - I get a NullPointerException!

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.sonarlint.eclipse.ui.internal.command.AnalyzeCommand.findSelectedFilesPerProject(AnalyzeCommand.java:94)

Comment: This is the session info from the Error log event details: eclipse.buildId=4.6.2.M20161124-1400
java.version=1.8.0_111
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_GB
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -clean -data file:/home/.../wksp_n2_git/